# Elementary Graph Theory: Number of Non Isomorphic N-Graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I want to partition the set $\mathcal{G}$ of $n$-graphs into $k$ disjoint and non-empty sets $\mathcal{G}_i$ with the property that if $A \in G_i$ and if $i \ne j$ then there exists no permutation of $A$ in $G_j$ and all permutations of $A$ are in $G_i$

It is simple, I think that
- Any $n$-graph has $n!$ permutations
- There are $2^\binom{n}{2}$ $n$-graphs

From the above, I was wondering if it is true that 
the partitioning I seek (1) is unique, and (2) there are $\frac{2^\binom{n}{2}}{n!}$ sets in the partition.

Answer (score 0):

All permutations of a given graph $A$ are in the same ${\mathcal G}_i$ as $A$, but you **didn't** state that those are all the members of ${\mathcal G}_i$.
So at one extreme, you could have each $\mathcal G_i$ be the set of permutations of one graph, at the other you could have only one $\mathcal G_1$ containing all the graphs.

Also, it's not that simple, because a permutation may leave the graph invariant.  For example, the complete graph on $n$ vertices is invariant under all permutations.  So is the completely disconnected graph ($n$ vertices and no edges).

Comment: Did my specifying non-empty solve the first issue you mention?

Comment: Not really.  If you're given the number $k$ of classes, you might split up the sets of permutations in lots of different ways.

Comment: Has my changed specification resulted in the partitioning I am aiming for

Comment: Yes, it has.  But still there's the issue of permutations leaving the graph invariant.

Comment: So how do I deal with this issue?